# Escape special characters while using cut along with find and exec

Tags: bash, unix, find, pipe, mv

I have to perform the following action on multiple files within a single folder:

> Remove "01 " like part from file names like "01 x y z.mp3".

To do that I have constructed following command:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c "mv "{}" `echo "{}" | cut -d' ' -f2-`" \;
```

But on executing the above command I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Up.mp3: not found
```

The first error is due to the '(' character present in the filenames and second error is due to the file name being "03 Up&Up.mp3". So in both the cases, the error is because sh cant escape the special characters.

Please suggest the suitable changes to correctly perform the above operation.

Comment: Did you try escaping such as: `find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c "mv \"{}\" \`echo \"{}\" | cut -d' ' -f2-\`" \;`?

Comment: @lurker shit dude that worked thanks

Comment: I would advise against using `cut` in this case because `find` will give you a subdirectory name in the string, which could contain spaces.  Stripping off the first field could also remove part or all of the subdirectory name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
find -name '*.mp3' -exec bash -c 'mv  "{}" "$(cut -d" " -f2- <<< "{}")"' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rename` tool

```
rename 's/^[0-9]+ //' *.mp3
```

note that this is not a standard tool in all linux distributions and refers to the perl script originally written by Larry Wall.  Refer to `man rename` to check what is available in your system.

Comment: I think you are referring to the rename tool that comes with perl. Yes, it is pretty nice but note that this tool is unfortunately not portable, not even between `GNU` systems. (Since it is not from GNU). For example on Gentoo there is a different version of rename with a pretty limited feature set.

Comment: Yes, I think it's originally written by Larry Wall.  Unfortunately non standard.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote on that, I mean the tool simply nails it down. You might add to your answer that you are referring to Larry Wall's version of `rename`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by escaping the "" used on the {}:

find . -name '*.mp3' -exec sh -c "mv \"{}\" `echo \"{}\" | cut -d' ' -f2-`" \;

Suggested by @lurker